# IMAP search not finding new email

Tags: python, email, imap

My test code sends an email with an attachment and saves a hash that is in the subject and body. I then have a function that takes the hash searches for it, gets the uid and fetches the email returning the attachment data.

The problem I am having is when I send a message and then subsequently search for the hash the email server says there is no matching uid, however if I run another copy of the script it does find it! Even if the second script is ran first! It first finds it but the original one doesn't; even though it is later!

Output

```
$ python test_server_file_functions.py 
Creating mail server
S: '* OK Gimap ready for requests from [ip] [data]'
C: '0001 CAPABILITY'
S: '* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2'
S: '0001 OK Thats all she wrote! [data]'
C: '0002 LOGIN "user@gmail.com" "password"'
S: '* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE'
S: '0002 OK user@gmail.com Anonymous Test authenticated (Success)'
C: '0003 SELECT INBOX'
S: '* FLAGS (\\Answered \\Flagged \\Draft \\Deleted \\Seen)'
S: '* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\\Answered \\Flagged \\Draft \\Deleted \\Seen \\*)] Flags permitted.'
S: '* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid.'
S: '* 0 EXISTS'
S: '* 0 RECENT'
S: '* OK [UIDNEXT 132] Predicted next UID.'
S: '0003 OK [READ-WRITE] INBOX selected. (Success)'
Does not exists
Created mail server
Sending email
Sent email
Waiting 3 minutes to make sure it isn't a simple delay with the email being relayed
Downloading Data...
C: '0004 SEARCH SUBJECT "EMS Data ID: 622904923b1825d5742ed25fb792fafe2e710c40ceea09660a604be8fabac35ae9b006c43c7a992159b8b0df376383830a6d4c54ed5b141c8429a4feec89cd8b"'
S: '* SEARCH'
S: '0004 OK SEARCH completed (Success)'
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/mail/imap4.py", line 2455, in _defaultHandler
    cmd.finish(rest, self._extraInfo)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/mail/imap4.py", line 382, in finish
    d.callback((send, lastLine))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 368, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 464, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/gms/gms/mail_backend.py", line 178, in process_download_uid
    raise IOError("Hash not found, however database indicates it was uploaded")
exceptions.IOError: Hash not found, however database indicates it was uploaded
There was an error retrieving the email
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/mail/imap4.py", line 2455, in _defaultHandler
    cmd.finish(rest, self._extraInfo)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/mail/imap4.py", line 382, in finish
    d.callback((send, lastLine))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 368, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 464, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/gms/gms/mail_backend.py", line 178, in process_download_uid
    raise IOError("Hash not found, however database indicates it was uploaded")
exceptions.IOError: Hash not found, however database indicates it was uploaded
Quiting...
```

Code

```
import os
# logging
from twisted.python import log

import sys
import time
import email

from Utils import BLOCK

# IMAP
from IMAPBackend import connectToIMAPServer, Command
# SMTP
from SMTPBackend import connectToSMTPServer

# Hash Database
from HashDatabase import HashDatabase, hash

# deferreds
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred, DeferredList, succeed
from twisted.internet.task import deferLater
#reactor
from twisted.internet import reactor


BLOCK_SIZE = BLOCK / 1024 # convert from bytes (needed for FTP) to kilobytes

def createMailServer(username, password, smtp_server, imap_server, hash_db = "hash.db"):
    # create smtp connection
    smtp_d = connectToSMTPServer(smtp_server, username, password)
    # create imap connection
    imap_d = connectToIMAPServer(imap_server, username, password)

    dl = DeferredList([smtp_d, imap_d])
    dl.addCallback(lambda r: [ MailServer(r[0][1], r[1][1], username, hash_db) ][0]  )
    return dl

class ServerManager(object):

    def __init__(self, mail_servers):

        self.mail_servers = mail_servers

    def get_server(self, accnt):
        for ms in self.mail_servers:
            if ms.account == accnt:
                return succeed(ms)

    def return_server(self):
        # retrieve the size avialable on the servers
        get_space_deferreds = []
        for ms in self.mail_servers:
            d = ms.get_space()
            d.addCallback(lambda r: (ms, r))
            get_space_deferreds.append(d)

        dl = DeferredList(get_space_deferreds, consumeErrors = True)
        dl.addCallback(self.parse_sizes)
        return dl

    def parse_sizes(self, results):
        for no_error, result in results:
            server = result[0]
            result = result[1]
            if no_error:# not an error so a potential server
                for argument in result[0]:
                    if argument[0] == "QUOTA":
                        print "Argument"
                        print argument
                        print "/Argument"
                        used, total =  argument[2][1:3]
                        available_kb = int(total) - int(used)
                        if available_kb >  BLOCK_SIZE:# server with more then our block size
                            return server
            else:
                print "Error from account %s" % server.email_address

        # no free space was found :-(
        raise IOError("No free space was found.")

class MailServer(object):
    "Manages a server"

    size = 0
    used_space = 0


    def __init__(self, smtp_connection, imap_connection, email_address, hash_db = "hash.db"):
        self.smtp_connection = smtp_connection
        self.imap_connection = imap_connection
        self.hash_database = HashDatabase(hash_db)
        self.email_address = email_address
        self.account = email_address

        # current uploads
        self.current_uploads = {}

        # current downloads
        self.current_downloads = {}
    def get_space(self):
        cmd = Command("GETQUOTAROOT", "INBOX", ["QUOTAROOT", "QUOTA"])
        d = self.imap_connection.sendCommand(cmd)
        return d

    def upload_data(self, data):
        """
            Uploads data to email server returns deferred that will return with the imap uid
            """
        data_hash = hash(data)
        if data_hash in self.current_uploads:
            d = Deferred()
            self.current_uploads[data_hash].append(d)
            return d

        if self.hash_database.hash_in_list(data_hash):
            print "Data hash is in the database; not uploading"
            return succeed(data_hash)

        else:
            d = Deferred()
            self.current_uploads[data_hash] = [d]
            id = "EMS Data ID: %s" % data_hash
            connection_deferred = self.smtp_connection.send_email(self.email_address, self.email_address, id, id, [["raw_ems", "ems.dat", data] ])


            connection_deferred.addCallback(self.upload_success, data_hash)
            connection_deferred.addErrback(self.upload_error, data_hash)
            connection_deferred.addBoth(self.notify_uploaders, data_hash)

        return d

    def notify_uploaders(self, result, data_hash):
        for waitingDeferred in self.current_uploads.pop(data_hash):
            # if r is a Failure, this is equivalent to calling .errback with
            # that Failure.
            waitingDeferred.callback(result)

    def upload_success(self, result, data_hash):

        # add to hash table
        self.hash_database.add_hash(data_hash)

        # immediatly searching doesn't seem to work so search on data retrieval
        return data_hash

    def upload_error(self, error, data_hash):
        # upload error
        log.msg("Erroring uploading file")
        log.err(error)
        return error # send error to uploader

    def download_data(self, data_hash):
        """
            Downloads data from the email server returns a deferred that will return with the data
            """
        d = Deferred()
        if data_hash in self.current_downloads:
            self.current_downloads[data_hash].append(d)
            return d

        if not self.hash_database.hash_in_list(data_hash):
            print "Data Hash has never been uploaded..."
            raise IOError("No such data hash exists")

        else:
            self.current_downloads[data_hash] = [d]
            id = "EMS Data ID: %s" % data_hash
            connection_deferred = self.imap_connection.search("SUBJECT", "\"EMS Data ID: %s\"" % data_hash, uid = False)
            connection_deferred.addCallback(self.process_download_uid)
            connection_deferred.addErrback(self.download_error, data_hash)
            connection_deferred.addBoth(self.notify_downloaders, data_hash)
            return d


        return d

    def process_download_uid(self, id):
        if len(id) == 0:
            raise IOError("Hash not found, however database indicates it was uploaded")
        d = self.imap_connection.fetchMessage(id[-1])
        d.addCallback(self.process_download_attachment, id[-1])
        return d

    def process_download_attachment(self, data, id):
        email_text = data[id]["RFC822"]
        msg = email.message_from_string(email_text)
        for part in msg.walk():
            type = part.get_content_type()
            print repr(type)
            if "raw_ems" in type:
                log.msg("Found Payload")
                return part.get_payload(decode = True)

        log.msg("No attachment found")
        raise IOError("Data not found")

    def download_error(self, error, data_hash):
        log.msg("Error downloading file")
        log.err(error)
        return error

    def notify_downloaders(self, result, data_hash):
        for waitingDeferred in self.current_downloads.pop(data_hash):
            # if r is a Failure, this is equivalent to calling .errback with
            # that Failure.
            waitingDeferred.callback(result)

    def delete_data(self, data_hash):
        if not self.hash_database.hash_in_list(data_hash):
            raise IOError("No such data hash uploaded")

        else:
            # delete it to prevent anyone from trying to download it while it is being deleted
            self.hash_database.delete_hash(data_hash)
            d = self.imap_connection.search("SUBJECT", "\"EMS Data ID: %s\"" % data_hash, uid = False)
            d.addCallback(self.delete_message)
            d.addErrback(self.deletion_error, data_hash)
            return d

    def deletion_error(self, error, data_hash):
        print "Deletion Error"
        log.err(error)
        # restore hash to database
        self.hash_database.add_hash(data_hash)

        raise IOError("Couldn't delete message hash")


    def delete_message(self, id):
        if len(id) == 0:
            raise IOError("Hash not found, however database indicates it was uploaded")
        d = self.imap_connection.setFlags(id[-1], ["\\Deleted"])
        d.addCallback(lambda result: self.imap_connection.expunge())
        return d


## Main Code ##

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def deleted_email(result):
        print "Deleted the email succesfully"
        print "====Result===="
        print result
        print "====Result===="
        print "Quiting..."
        os._exit(0)

    def error_deleting(error):
        print "There was an error deleting the email"
        error.printTraceback()
        print "Quiting..."
        os._exit(0)

    def retrieved_data(result, ms, hash):
        print "Retrieved data"
        print "=====Data===="
        print result
        print "Deleting email"

        d = ms.delete_data(hash)
        d.addCallback(deleted_email)
        d.addErrback(error_deleting)

        return d

    def email_retrieval_error(error):
        print "There was an error retrieving the email"
        error.printTraceback()
        print "Quiting..."
        os._exit(0)


    def sent_email(hash, ms):
        print "Sent email"
        print "Waiting 3 minutes to make sure it isn't a simple delay with the email being relayed"
        time.sleep(3 * 60)
        print "Downloading Data..."
        d = ms.download_data(hash)
        d.addCallback(retrieved_data, ms, hash)
        d.addErrback(email_retrieval_error)

        return d

    def email_sending_error(error):
        print "There was an error sending the email"
        error.printTraceback()
        print "Quiting..."
        os._exit(0)


    def mail_server_created(ms):
        # created mail server
        print "Created mail server"
        print "Sending email"
        d = ms.upload_data("this is the attachment data I am sending to my email account")
        d.addCallback(sent_email, ms)
        d.addErrback(email_sending_error)

        return d

    def mail_server_error(error):
        print "Error creating mail server"
        error.printTraceback()
        print "Quiting..."
        os._exit(0)




    # create mail server object
    print "Creating mail server"
    d = createMailServer("user@gmail.com", "password", "smtp.gmail.com:587", "imap.gmail.com:993", hash_db = "testhash.db")
    d.addCallback(mail_server_created)
    d.addCallback(mail_server_error)

    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.run()
```

I am thinking I may have to re-select the mailbox? I look in the RFC3501 select and search commands and found nothing about such a problem

Comment: Sorry but I didn't fully understand the question. For one thing, there is too much code. More importantly, you mention two scripts - which are they?

Comment: Sorry I will write a simpler script...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search command works on the data which is collected by parsing the entire mail folder which is been selected by Select command

You will have to select the mail folder again to get the mail entry updated.

Search result will not have the new mail input unless the server has implemented the IDLE/NOOP functionality (again it solely depends on mail server)

Comment: I'm interested in IDLE functionality of mail server. I've read in 'RFC 2177' that client needs to send 'done' in order to end the continuation of client commands. [Link here]: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2177
Could you suggest on how to send it?